# MySQL conditional LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: `albums`, `songs`, and `images`.
The tables look something like this:

`albums` table:

```
id   |     title     |   image_id
5    |  First Album  |      1
6    | Another Album |      2
```

`songs` table:

```
id    |   album_id   |     title     |   image_id
32    |      5       |    My Song    |      3
33    |      5       |  Another One  |      4
34    |      5       |   First Song  |      0
35    |      6       |   My Song #2  |      0
36    |      6       |  Fancy Title  |      0
37    |      6       |  My Love Song |      5
```

`images` table:

```
id   |     path
1    | path/to/image1.jpg
2    | path/to/image2.jpg
3    | path/to/image3.jpg
4    | path/to/image4.jpg
5    | path/to/image5.jpg
```

I am trying to display a list of songs with their titles and corresponding images.

If the songs don't have an image (if the `image_id` column is `0`), then I want to just use the album image.

The only code I have so far is this, and I am stuck:

```
SELECT songs.title, images.path
FROM songs
LEFT JOIN images
ON images.id = songs.image_id

// ...if songs.image_id is 0, i want to just use the image_id of the corresponding album instead
```

It would be nice if it was an efficient query that could work with large tables.

Comment: Use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: Performance-wise, it might be better to use NULL instead of 0. That way, the database knows that there can be no matching row before even trying to JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using multiple LEFT JOINs, with demo using data you provided.

The final query:

```
SELECT 
    s.title, 
    COALESCE(i1.path, i2.path)
FROM songs s
LEFT JOIN albums a ON s.album_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN images i1 ON s.image_id = i1.id
LEFT JOIN images i2 ON a.image_id = i2.id
ORDER BY s.id;
```

Below is a full demo.

SQL:

```
-- Data for demo
create table albums(id int, title char(100), image_id int);
insert into albums values
(5    ,  'First Album'  ,      1),
(6    , 'Another Album' ,      2);

create table songs(id int, album_id int, title char(100), image_id int);
insert into songs values
(32    ,      5       ,    'My Song'    ,      3),
(33    ,      5       ,  'Another One'  ,      4),
(34    ,      5       ,   'First Song'  ,      0),
(35    ,      6       ,   'My Song #2'  ,      0),
(36    ,      6       ,  'Fancy Title'  ,      0),
(37    ,      6       ,  'My Love Song' ,      5);

create table images(id int, path char(200));
insert into images values
(1    , 'path/to/image1.jpg'),
(2    , 'path/to/image2.jpg'),
(3    , 'path/to/image3.jpg'),
(4    , 'path/to/image4.jpg'),
(5    , 'path/to/image5.jpg');

SELECT * FROM albums;
SELECT * FROM songs;
SELECT * FROM images;

-- SQL needed 
SELECT 
    s.title, 
    COALESCE(i1.path, i2.path)
FROM songs s
LEFT JOIN albums a ON s.album_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN images i1 ON s.image_id = i1.id
LEFT JOIN images i2 ON a.image_id = i2.id
ORDER BY s.id;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> s.title,
    -> COALESCE(i1.path, i2.path)
    -> FROM songs s
    -> LEFT JOIN albums a ON s.album_id = a.id
    -> LEFT JOIN images i1 ON s.image_id = i1.id
    -> LEFT JOIN images i2 ON a.image_id = i2.id
    -> ORDER BY s.id;
+--------------+----------------------------+
| title        | COALESCE(i1.path, i2.path) |
+--------------+----------------------------+
| My Song      | path/to/image3.jpg         |
| Another One  | path/to/image4.jpg         |
| First Song   | path/to/image1.jpg         |
| My Song #2   | path/to/image2.jpg         |
| Fancy Title  | path/to/image2.jpg         |
| My Love Song | path/to/image5.jpg         |
+--------------+----------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT s.title, COALESCE(si.path, ai.path)
FROM albums AS a
INNER JOIN songs s ON a.id = s.album_id
LEFT JOIN images ai ON i.id = a.image_id
LEFT JOIN images si ON i.id = s.image_id
```

Note that you have to join the `images` table to the `albums` table AND to the `songs` table. `ai` and `si` serve as separate namespacing for these joins so that [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) knows how to find options to choose from.

(Note that the `INNER JOIN` is debatable depending on how you expect your data to look.)

Comment: Better put songs on top. Otherwise it won't return any songs without album.

Comment: @Thilo Good catch. Fixing!

Comment: COALESCE is insufficient, since he has 0 rather than NULL for missing images. But the tweak to handle that is not major.

Comment: @mdahlman The fact that `si.path` should be `NULL` (because the join wouldn't find a row) should be sufficient, though, right? (I don't actually have a db available I can try this out on atm.)

Comment: @NathanielFord, yes you are correct. My mistake. But COALESCE(s.path, ai.path) should be COALESCE(si.path, ai.path)

Comment: To come back to "conditional left join part", one could say `LEFT JOIN images ai ON ai.id = a.image_id AND s.image_id = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use UNION in this way:

```
SELECT songs.title, images.path
FROM songs
LEFT JOIN images ON (images.id = songs.image_id)
WHERE songs.image_id != 0
UNION
SELECT songs.title, images.path
FROM songs
LEFT JOIN albums ON (songs.album_id = albums.id)
LEFT JOIN images ON (images.id = albums.image_id)
WHERE albums.image_id != 0 AND songs.image_id = 0
```

Basically you first select all the songs with an image, then append all the songs with an album image if the song itself doesn't have it.